# Put view between two Views with strict size

Tags: android, android-view

Is there any way to put my `FrameLayout` between 1.1 and 1.3.
I tried to use `layout_below` and `layout_above` for it, but it doesn't work together.

1.`RelativeLayout`

1.1`RelativeLayout` (strict_size)

1.2`FrameLayout` (match_parent)

1.3`RelativeLayout`(strict_size)

Comment: share your xml code and the output you want so it will be good to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `LinearLayout`. Assuming you are talking about heights:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp">

</LinearLayout>
```

When using `layout_weight` like that, `LinearLayout` will first lay out views with fixed dimensions, and then assign all the remaining space to the `layout_weight="1"` view.